# Data consistency in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to use DynamoDB for a large scale service which would be accessed by many users within a second. I want to know how correct would be the read data from DynamoDb which provides "Eventual Consistent" reads.

This link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/APISummary.html says
"Consistency across all copies of the data is usually reached within a second". I haven't tried testing SQL DBs for such highly accessed databases, but the service provided by DynamoDB doesn't seem to be better at least.

The strongly consistent read is costly and may take more time, so I prefer the normal reads. If necessary I'll have to check for strongly consistent read.

I am little bit afraid of the "Eventual" word. Has anyone seen such a scenario where DynamoDB is being successfully used or the other way round, i.e. the inconsistent results read were found ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you talk about your usecase a little more?

For many use cases, when end users are just reading data out of the table it's not crucial that the data be exact and update to date right to the second..especially if you can save 50% on read throughput costs by using eventually consistent reads. If you NEED consistent reads...then use consistent reads.

I generally use eventually consistent reads in my application and have never noticed an occurrence of inconsistent data. I only use strongly consistent reads when my application needs it.

Comment: In my usecase the number of concurrent users can be upto 10k or more. And with each access there is both a read and write operation. So I was wondering whether this property of DynamoDB will be OK or not.

I tested with some 1000 users and it's working fine. I think that if I properly time reads and writes, then it should not be an issue.